# How to do a api request on the server side before rendering the page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a JS script on a page that makes a call to Y server on page load and it displays some data. If you look on page source you can see the script making the call to Y server.

**What I need to do instead** is make the api request to Y server from MY server and render the page to client completed without the JS scripts. So if you look at the page source you will not see any reference to Y server because that will all have happened on my server in the background before the page was rendered to the client.

*Does anyone know how this setup can be accomplished?* Looking for guidance... Links to docs? Please ask for clarification if unclear.

Comment: Where is the source code?

Comment: Why not process your api call, then perform a redirect along with the data from the api call to the frontend script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a high level, you'll need to:

1. Implement an HTTP client for the API
2. Add code that calls the API (probably in a controller, but it could be a helper, model or service object)
3. (Optionally) parse the response (this depends on what format it's in and what format you need)
4. Render the parsed response in the view

2 & 4 are easy. 3 is going to be up to you, unless you can provide concrete examples. It should be easy, though. That leaves 1.

If you're using a popular API, there's a good chance that a [client has already been written](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/api_clients). If it's something in house, you can write something custom using Net::HTTP or one of the other [popular HTTP client libraries](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients). As long as you don't need to send along any cookies/headers from the browser, this should be really easy.

Here's a quick example of how this could look using [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and an API that returns HTML.

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @mydata = RestClient.get('http://path.to/your/api?with=params')
  end
end

# /app/views/index.html.erb
<h1>Here's Your Data</h1>
<%= raw @mydata %>
```

Comment: I can't believe how easy that was. RestClient gem and James Mason save the day! Thanks buddy! +1

Answer (score 0):

what you need, is to generate directly your html from your server, and render a dynamic page.
You'll have to general your html from your templates, and render it directly to the client.
For example, php, you'll have your .twig file with php variables instead of your static html.
The same goes for java, with your servlets.
The page is rendered Back side, and sent as static file to the client.
Not sure for the exact method for ROR.

I'm trying a simple example. imagine that the variable data contain the elements you want to get from your api, here is your 2 ex :

//first case
 staticPage1.html
[...]
var data=loadAjax(url)
window.console.log(data);
//the page served from the back is the same in the front


//second case
 generated.someServerSideTemplate
 [...]

 var data={{getDataFromUrl(url)}}
//some server side templating language

 
generated.html
 [...]

 
var data={"message":"hello world"} // actual page rendered

 
 
i hope it's clear...

Comment: From the tags, it looks like the backend is Rails.

Comment: Thanks, i'm editing it as examples of implementation

Comment: Please don't put mult-line code in comments as it isn't readable.  Use the "edit" link and add this info to your answer where you can format it appropriately.